# What is a Bag of Devouring's Storage Capacity for Living Creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Page 153 DMG:

*Bag of Devouring*

> This bag superficially resembles a Bag of holding.

+

> Inanimate objects can be stored in the bag, which can hold a cubic
>   foot of such material.

+

> When part of a living creature is placed in the bag, as happens when
>   someone reaches inside it, there is a 50 percent chance that the
>   creature is pulled inside the bag.

*Bag of Holding*

> This bag has an interior space considerably larger than its outside
>   dimensions, roughly 2 feet in diameter at the mouth and 4 feet deep.

**Storage Capacity**

As the bag superficially resembles a Bag of Holding, that means it is 2 feet in diameter at the mouth and 4 feet deep. Internally, it is explicitly stated that it holds up to 1 cubic foot of inanimate objects.

*Given these measurements, what is its internal storage capacity for living creatures that are pulled into the bag, and how does its 2-foot diameter mouth change (if at all) depending on creature size?*

A Medium sized creature could fit through a 2-foot opening, but what happens when a Gargantuan Brontosaurus sticks its head into it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Size of the creature does not matter

**DMG, page 153:**

> When part of a **living creature** is placed
>   in the bag, as happens when someone reaches inside it,
>   there is a 50 percent chance that the creature is pulled
>   inside the bag. A creature inside the bag can use its
>   action to try to escape with a successful DC 15 Strength
>   check. Another creature can use its action to reach into
>   the bag to pull a creature out, doing so with a successful
>   DC 20 Strength check (provided it isn't pulled inside the
>   bag first). **Any creature that starts its turn inside the bag
>   is devoured, its body destroyed**.

There is no word about size of the creature. So **RAW** it's no matter.

It's a wondrous item, friend, standard measurements here do not rule :)